# How to use Bubble sort in linked list without swapping the nodes?

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list, bubble-sort

I am trying to use bubble sort to sort a linked list. Instead of swapping the nodes, why can't I swap the values of the nodes and produce the desired output? The below code was my approach.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void sort_ll(struct node *head){
    struct node *p1 = head;
    struct node *p2 = NULL;
    while(p1->next!=NULL){
        p2 = p1;
        int temp;
        while(p2->next!=NULL){
            if(p2->data>p1->data){
                temp = p2->data;
                p2->data = p1->data;
                p1->data = temp;
            }
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
    print_ll(p1);
}
```

Comment: Sure you can swap the data, but if the caller of your function has some references to nodes in the list, they may not want that the values of those nodes suddenly changed, but want to rest assured that sorting will not alter the node's values.

Comment: Is there any problem with your code? It is actually not clear what you are asking...